# Pluck and Implode Method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-controller, laravel-models

I have three classes Student, Session and student classes it has a relationship (Student with Enrollment, Session with Enrollment and student Class with enrollment), when I do echo it show the result
[{"id":1,"school_id":1,"class_id":1,"student_id":1,"session_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}] ,i have plucked value from student class

```
{{implode(',',$en->school()->get()->pluck('school_name')->toArray())}}
```

Note it is working

---

same from Session it is also working but when I plucked from student class and need class_name it not show an error but not the plucked value from studentclass here is the same type of query in blade.php

```
{{implode(',',$en->studentclass()->get()->pluck('class_name')->toArray())}}
```

---

here is the relationship one to many in StudentClass Controller

```
public function enrollments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Enrollement::class);
    }
```

Enrollement Class

```
public function studentclass()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(StudentClass::class);
    }
```

how to pick the class_name value from table using this relationship. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, note that you can use the `implode` method on the illuminate/collection method:

```
{{ $en->school()->get()->pluck('school_name')->implode(', ') }}
```

which can be further shortened to

```
{{ $en->school->pluck('school_name')->implode(', ') }}
```

The studentclass can be plucked like so

```
{{ $en->studentclass->pluck('enrollments.class_name')->implode(', ') }}
```

using dot syntax to access the class name.

to prevent this from creating a n+1 issue and reduce the number of queries ran, you should lazy load the relationship:

```
{{ $en->load('studentclass.enrollments')->studentclass->pluck('enrollments.class_name')->implode(', ') }}
```

you could also load it in advance:

```php
$en = Enrollment::with('studentclass.enrollments')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: {{$en->school()->pluck('school_name')->implode(', ') }}  or {{implode(',',$en->school()->get()->pluck('school_name')->toArray())}} Both work but it not work to pick the class_name from studentclass function even Relationship is OK , if i echo the $en it get the class_id from Enrollement class

Comment: echo $en show the following result [{"id":1,"school_id":1,"class_id":1,"student_id":1,"session_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}] it mean we have class_id why we cannot pick the class_name using relationship function studentclass in Enrollement Model

Comment: If you see the second example in my answer, it shows how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pluck the relationship's column using simple **`.`** notation as given below.

```php
{{ implode(',', $en->studentclass()->pluck('studentclass.class_name')->toArray()) }}
```

Here, it forms as, `relationship`**.**`column`

Comment: {{$en->school()->pluck('school_name')->implode(', ') }}  or {{implode(',',$en->school()->get()->pluck('school_name')->toArray())}} Both work but it not work to pick the class_name from studentclass function even Relationship is OK , if i echo the $en it get the class_id from Enrollement class

Comment: echo $en show the following result [{"id":1,"school_id":1,"class_id":1,"student_id":1,"session_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}] it mean we have class_id why we cannot pick the class_name using relationship function studentclass in Enrollement Model

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the studentclass function in Enrollment Model

```
public function studentclass()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(StudentClass::class,'id');
    }
```

just by adding, 'id' and pluck from view

```
{{implode(',',$en->studentclass()->get()->pluck('class_name')->toArray())}}
```